# Display an SVG from web URL in MAUI

Tags: svg, maui, .net-maui, ffimageloading

I am converting my Xamarin Forms Application to .NET MAUI.

In existing app we have used FFImageLoader for loading svg image from url but this library doesn't support .net MAUI.

According to this [Link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10050) it's not currently supported in MAUI and has been moved to backlog.
Is there any alternative approach?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: the workaround suggested in the link you posted is download the image locally and then display from a file

Comment: 1- you download the svg and display it from source "your resource path"
2- you can test if a webview works = <WebView Source="https://yourSvgUrl" />

Comment: So you have a URL and you wanna load that SVG? I have a NuGet package I created for SVG loading and more but I still need to implement loading from a URL though https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreakyControls

Comment: I don't want to download the image locally, cause I need to load multiple images at once and it will take up lot of memory space.

Comment: So you can try to use the second method Leandro Tolaza proviced, it's hard to implement  the FFImageLoader's function in the maui by yourself.